# Block pinch zoom gesture in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have an application that embeds contents in one or more iframe tags in the page.

These contents can, as option, be an HTML page chose by backoffice and loaded into the iframe.

I have to disable the pinch zoom gesture for mobile devices but i cannot edit the content as it's an iframe, so i can't add meta tags.

Also, using `touch-events: none` in CSS on the iframe tag seems not working

Any solutions?

Comment: You can't modify an iframe without an intervent of who made it

Comment: You can't alter an iFrame content like that. If you don't have access to the iFrame source I don't think it's possible to do anything.

Comment: What if we add a transparent DOM element over the iFrame and try to prevent pinch zoom events, and pass all others? 